# Opening apps in the Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-intent

when I try to open apps in the Google Play Store I keep getting the page not found sheet and I want to know why and how to go ahead and open these apps in the Google Play Store

Answer (score 0):

use this code to open that:

`Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("GOOGLE PLAY LINK"));
startActivity(i);`

if it doesn't work, you may have other application wich make confliction. To handle this, you should uninstall that app or go to :
Settings> Apps> "That Application" > Clear Defaults.